# Description of Czech consonants

Tags: terminology

I don't speak any Slavonic languages and am merely seeking a fuller understanding of what R.G.A. De Bray has to say in his book ' Guide to the Slavonic Languages ' . For one thing , on page 369 , he mentions ' The palatal consonants of Czech and Slovak : ť , ď , ň , ř ( Czech only ) ... but on page 442 he tells us about ' the palatalized ď , ť , ň , ř , and j ... '  My question , please , is simply : why does he call the SAME individual four consonants ď , ť , ň , ř ' palatal ' on the first of those two pages but ' palatalized ' on the second page ? Assuming these two terms are not synonymous , it puzzles me that he applies two somewhat similar but nonetheless  DIFFERENT terms to the very SAME individual consonants . There ought to be a rational explanation .

Answer (score 1):

I suppose "palatal" is a misnomer. In Slavic languages themselves, they are termed, literally, "soft consonants" (Czech: **měkké souhlásky**, Slovak: **mäkké spoluhlásky**). While palatalisation is sometimes called "softening", one doesn't customarily speak of "softened" consonants, but of soft/hard "pairs" or "counterparts". This Slavic choice of adjective referring, as it were, to being and not becoming, may have influenced the author's not-quite-correct choice of "palatal" instead of "palatalised".

Also, I don't think it's correct to call `j` palatal*ised*, when it obviously has no non-palatalised counterpart. Also, if those quotes are complete, they fail to mention the Slovak-only `ľ`. So I'd put this down to simple carelessness.

Comment: Thank you . It looks like I shall just have to accept that where De Bray says ' palatal ' he ought to have said ' palatalized ' instead . For the record I should point out that where he cites j in my quote he does so after the word ' and ' , and so it's conceivable that he didn't mean to apply the term ' palatalized ' to j : he may perhaps  simply have tagged j on to the list because his topic is actually the changing of certain vowels after the palatalized consonants and such changes occur also after j .

Comment: Czech and Slovak put aside, since you spoke about the Slavic languages in general I should note, that Ukrainian has both palatal (Ukr. _м'які_, Ru. _мягкие_) and palatalized (Ukr. _пом'якшені_, Ru. _смягчённые_) consonants. It means in Ukrainian some consonant phonemes (like /n/, /t/, /l/, /s/, etc.) have palatal counterparts (/nʲ/, /tʲ/, /lʲ/, /sʲ/, etc.), while other consonant phonemes (like /m/, /p/, /b/, /f/, etc.) don't, still they have palatalized allophones before the front vowel /i/: [mʲ], [pʲ], [bʲ], [fʲ].

Comment: So in Ukrainian the description  ' palatalized consonant ' may be correctly applied to the consonant phonemes that have palatal counterparts while the description ' palatal consonant ' may equally correctly be applied to those consonant phonemes that do NOT have palatal counterparts . I take it that you're saying that the description ' palatal consonant ' ought not be applied to ANY consonant in ANY of the other ten Slavonic languages recognized in De Bray's chapter headings : Russian , Byelorussian , Bulgarian , Macedonian , Serbocroatian , Slovenian , Czech , Slovak , Polish , and Lusatian .

Comment: @YellowSky They *can* be called **změkčené/zmäkčené** too, but the thing is, in at least three of the four languages mentioned so far (can't speak for Ukrainian), it's not a *common* way to talk about them. One does not immediately think of them as "-ized" as opposed to just "being this way". And that might explain De Bray's choice of terminology.

Comment: As a native Czech speaker (but non-linguist), I can say I see terms soft/hard (literal translation of měkké/tvrdé) almost exclusively. I've probably once heard of palatization in this meaning, before reading this question. When speaking about soft consonants, there are more than those listed as palatized: ž [ʒ], š [ʃ], č [t͡ʃ], ř [r̝]/[r̝̊], ď [ɟ], ť [c], ň [ɲ]. They correspond to letters with caron (háček), except ě.

Comment: Well, there are two more than “soft” consonants: c [t͡s] and j [j]. Those however don't have a “hard” counterpart, unlike others. The reason why those two are “soft” is probably not related to pronunciation, only to orthography (“y” vs. “i” after them). But this might be the reason why “j” is mentioned as “palatized”.

Comment: So it would seem  the term ' soft ' applies to a wider range of consonants than does the term  ' palatalized ' . That is also of interest , since De Bray does in fact use the term ' soft consonant ' too , not only with respect to Czech . At the point on page 442 that I mentioned earlier , in Section B , he writes of vowel mutation after palatalized and formerly palatalized consonants but on page 452 he refers you back to that SAME spot , and hence to the SAME phenomenon ,  of vowel mutation , by saying ' see ...B ' , yet on the latter page he says ' after soft and formerly soft consonants ' .